# Boot problem after deleting Windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, kubuntu

I am new to linux. I had dual boot kubuntu and Windows 8. After a while I decided to keep only kubuntu, so I started GParted and deleted windows partitions. But now I can't boot into kubuntu, in bios I get Ubuntu (drive not present) in boot options. I tried to use Boot Repair, but it didn't help. Here are screenshots of current situation from GParted: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5ZaH.jpg

Thank you in advance

Comment: You'll get faster help if you describe the situation rather than linking an image about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstalling grub will do.

- Boot into a Ubuntu Live Media.
- Then chroot into your exisitng root,

  ```
  sudo mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt/
  sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/boot/efi

  sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
  sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
  sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
  sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys

  sudo chroot /mnt
  ```
- Reinstall Grub

  ```
  grub-install
  ```

Full tutorial can be found [here](http://www.linuxdeveloper.space/install-windows-after-linux/).

**NOTE: sdbX values may change. The commands are for device given the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5ZaH.jpg)**